# Clarification needed regarding getchar() and newline

Tags: c++, c, getchar

I have a doubt regarding using `getchar()` to read a character input from the user.

```
char char1, char2;
char1 = getchar();
char2 = getchar();
```

I need to get `2` chars as inputs from the user. In this case, if the user enters the character `'A'` followed by a `newline`, and then the character `'B'`, what will be stored in `char2` - will it be the newline character or the character `'B'`?

I tried it on CodeBlocks on Windows, and `char2` actually stores the newline character, but I intended it to store the character `'B'`.

I just want to know what the expected behavior is, and whether it is compiler-dependent? If so, what differences hold between turbo C and mingW?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you have to consume newlines after each input:

```
char1 = getchar();
getchar(); // To consume `\n`
char2 = getchar();
getchar(); // To consume `\n`
```

This is not compiler-dependent. This is true for all platforms as there'll be carriage return at the end of each input line (Although the actual line feed may vary across platforms).

Comment: one little question: will getchar() simply flushed the data, take any space to save the  LF?

Comment: @hikaru89 getchar() call simply returns the *value*. If it's not saved in the program (as the 2nd and 4th calls here), it's discarded and doesn't involve any additional storage.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know what the expected behavior is, and whether it depends on the compiler-dependent?

That's the expected behavior and not compiler-dependent.

You can use `scanf` to read A followed by newline, then B followed by newline. If you want to stick to `getchar()`, then simply give the input as `AB`.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent reading newlines by explicitly testing for it.
Instead of simply using

```
getchar():
```

you can use something like this

```
while((char1 = getchar()) == '\n');
```

If you're on windows you might want to test for '\r' too. So the code changes a little.

```
while((char1 = getchar()) == '\n' || char1 == '\r');
```

Answer (score -2):

add statement `fflush(stdin);` in between  statements.
look this one

```
ch1=getchar();

fflush(stdin);
ch2=getchar();
```

Comment: fflush() on an input stream is undefined behavior according to the C standard. It works on Windows, at least in Visual Studio, but should probably be avoided since it is non-standard.