# The program control flow doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, getchar

This is a problem in `C`. The program Control flow is not as expected. It ask to enter the character in but fail to ask to enter character x.

```
int foo();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    foo();
    return 0;
}



int foo(){

    char in;
    char x;
    printf("Do you wanna party \n");


    if((in = getchar()) == 'y')
        printf("Go Sleep!, I was kidding\n");
    else
        printf("Oh! you are so boaring..\n");


    printf("\nOk, Another Question\n");
    printf("Wanna Go to Sleep\n");


    if((x = getchar()) == 'y')
        printf("ok lets go, Sleepy Head\n");
    else
        printf("No, lets go\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you handling the newline correctly? Recall that most terminals only send input on receipt of a newline, which will appear in `getchar`'s input.

Comment: Its spelled "boring" BTW. You can also reuse the variable `in` you dont need to declare a second `x` to handle input.

Comment: @nneonneo

Do you wanna party 
in = y
Go Sleep!, I was kidding

After this no input is asked by program. The following output is displayed

Ok, Another Question
Wanna Go to Sleep
No, lets go

Program ended with exit code: 0

This is the output I got when I run the program

Comment: See related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544068/clarification-needed-regarding-getchar-and-newline

Comment: @RSahu The question is different. Here x = getchar() doesn't ask for input. The output just displayed. I tried to print the value for x. It's just a blank space

Comment: @Surajharikrishan, add a `getline()` after the line containing `in = getchar()` and before the line containing `x = getchar()`.

Answer (score 6):

To clarify the comments mentioned above, in the process of giving input, you're pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. So, the `y` is considered as the input to first `getchar()`, and the `ENTER` key press [`\n`] is stored in the input buffer.

On the call to next `getchar()`, the `\n` is read, which is considered a perfectly valid input for `getchar()` and hence your code is not waiting for the next input.

Comment: But even if I use scanf() the answer is same. 
I also tried the input y y just in case for getchar() but, it didn't work

Comment: @Surajharikrishan i was expecting this question next. Well, a `\n` is valid for `%c` modifier also. To avoid, write your `scanf()` like `scanf(" %c", &input);`, minding the extra space in `" %c"`.