# C getchar() hangman game

Tags: c, getchar

I was given a homework assignment which tasked us with creating a simple hangman game. Below is the code I have. I am currently trying to use if else with `getchar()` to ask the user to input a lowercase letter and see if it matches one of the letters in the word they are supposed to guess. From my very limited experience the code I have should work and when I step through the program it appears as if it should run properly, but when I actually run the program it seems to skip over the second `getchar()`. Anyone have any suggestions or help?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

int main(void) {
    int(a);
    int(b);
    float(x);
    float(c);
    float(e);

    int word[4] = {116, 101, 115, 116};
    int guess[4];

    c == 0;
    a == 0;
    b == 0;

    printf("Welcome to Hangman\n");
    printf("Input a word--one lower case letter at a time\n");
    printf("Enter Guess: ");

    x = getchar();

    if (x > 122) {
        printf(" Error, character must be a lowercase letter");
    } else
    if (x < 97) {
        printf(" Error, character must be a lowercase letter");
    } else
    if (x == 116) {
        printf("t is correct\n");

        printf("%d", word[0]);
        printf(" _");
        printf(" _");
        printf(" %d ", word[3]);

        e = getchar();

        if (e == 101) {
            printf("e is correct\n");

            printf("%d", word[0]);
            printf(" %d", word[1]);
            printf(" _");
            printf(" %d ", word[3]);
        } else
        if (e == 115) {
            printf("s is correct\n");

            printf("%d", word[0]);
            printf(" _");
            printf(" %d", word[2]);
            printf(" %d", word[0]);
        } else {
            printf(" You guessed wrong");
        }
    } else
    if (x == 101) {
        printf("e is correct\n");
        printf("_");
        printf(" %d", word[1]);
        printf(" _");
        printf(" _ ");
    } else
    if (x == 115) {
        printf("s is correct\n");

        printf("_");
        printf(" _");
        printf(" %d", word[2]);
        printf(" _ ");
    } else {
        printf(" You guessed wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `int(a);` ...  Your declarations are incorrect for starters... Try `int a;` Also `a == 0;` is a comparison of `a` to zero, **not** an *assignment of zero to* `a`, try `a = 0;`

Comment: This is garbage code.

Comment: `c == 0;` et al. don't do anything.

Comment: There are several problems here.  But your main question is about `getchar()`. The answer is that you're forgetting about the NEWLINE character:  [Clarification needed regarding getchar() and newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544068/clarification-needed-regarding-getchar-and-newline)

Comment: You mustn't write a separate if statement for each character. That's just not how to do it. If you find yourself writing the same line of code a second time chances are you're doing something wrong.

Comment: You should drop those useless blank lines. Not all, only the useless ones.

Comment: Why are you using an integer array? just use `char word[5] = "test"`. And think about your code. Use a second array to store the correct guesses and iterate over the field of characters in order to check the input.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it is valid to add parentheses around the name in declarations, but otherwise this code is pure garbage.

Answer (score 2):

When you input a character that you want [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) to read, you end it with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key right? That <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will *also* be put into the input buffer of `stdin` (which is what `getchar` reads from) as a newline, `'\n'`.

That means for each input you give, you actually input *two* characters.

You need to skip that newline. This can easily be done by just adding a second `getchar` after the first, like for example

```
x = getchar();
getchar();  // Read the newline from the Enter key
```

Comment: And `x` should be type `int` so you can check `if (x == EOF) { return 1; }` on the user canceling input **before** your second `getchar` or you will be blocking on the second `getchar`.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a good answer, but to clarify the 
problem a little bit more, here is a simple piece of code.
The function get_character will return the first entered character
and consume all following characters until the next `'\n'`.

It is not going to block if one character is EOF.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int get_character(void);

int main(void)
{
        printf("character > ");
        int c = get_character();
        while(c != EOF && c != 'q')
        {
                printf("You entered %c\n", c); 
                printf("character > ");
                c = get_character();
        }
}

int get_character(void)
{
        int c = getchar(), next_c;
        if(c == EOF)
        {
                return EOF;
        }
        next_c = getchar(); // consume all \n
        while(next_c != '\n' && next_c != EOF)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: consumed non-newline character: 0x%x\n", next_c); 
                next_c = getchar(); 
        }
        return c;
}
```

By the way: You are able to solve the hangman way faster:

```
int get_character(void);
#define MAX_TRIALS 3
#define WORD_LEN 4

int main(void)
{
    char word[WORD_LEN + 1] = "test";
    char correct[WORD_LEN] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    int trials = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(trials > MAX_TRIALS)
        {
            printf("You failed. The word was: %s\n", word);
            return 0;
        }

        printf("character > ");
        int c = get_character();
        if(c == EOF)
        {
            printf("bye\n");
            return 0;
        }

        int i, this_char_correct = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < WORD_LEN; i++)
        {
            if(c == word[i])
            {
                correct[i] = 1;
                this_char_correct = 1;
            }
            if(correct[i])
            {
                printf("%c", word[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("_");
            }
        }
        if(!this_char_correct)
        {
            trials++;
        }
        int word_done = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < WORD_LEN; i++)
        {
            word_done &= correct[i];
        }
        if(! word_done)
        {
            printf("\nYou have %d trials left\n", WORD_LEN - trials);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nYou got it.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a piece of proof-of-concept code there might be way more elegant ways to solve this.