# ask user for input in a swich statement that will generate another swich in c

Tags: c, newline, getchar

how to ask user for input in a switch statement  that will generate another switch in c, I tried this but my program crashed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char choise1, choise2;

    printf("Starting menu:\n a -> Start\n");
    choise1 = getchar();

    switch(choise1){

    case 'a':
        printf("\n a -> New Game\n b -> Load Game");
        choise2 = getchar();
        switch(choise2){
        case 'a':
            printf("Start new game.");
            break;
        case 'b':
            printf("Loading game.");
            break;
        default:
            printf("This is a wrong input.");
        }
        break;

    default:
        printf("This is a wrong input.");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clarification needed regarding getchar() and newline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544068/clarification-needed-regarding-getchar-and-newline)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here as I see it is due to the remaining input the input buffer.

When you input <kbd>a</kbd> and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, a `newline` is stored after the `a` in the input buffer, which will be returned in the next call to `getchar()`.

If you want successive call to `getchar()` to return the *valid* inputs, you need to clear the input buffer of the existing content before you can read in next input. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898516/2173917) for some well-explained methods.

That said,

- [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) returns an `int` and for some of the return values, like `EOF`, it may not fit into a `char`. Change the `choise1` and `choise2` types to `int`.
- `int main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, for a hosted environment to conform to the standard.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7898516/1485885) to do so.

Comment: @cbuchart Yep, nice anchor. :)