# Why I could not print char variable?

Tags: c

I don't know why this basic code doesn't work well: it's printing just the first variable but not the second:
b=a
y=b

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int b, y;
    b = getchar();
    putchar(b);
    y = getchar();
    putchar(y);
    return 0;
}
```

```
The output is:
/tmp/urA18H7eDx.o
a
a
b
dash: 2: b: not found
```

Comment: Your second `getchar()` reads a newline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544068/clarification-needed-regarding-getchar-and-newline
You need additional `getchar()` call to consume a newline

Comment: The first character read is `a`, and the second character read is `\n`.  Both characters are read after the newline is entered.  The program outputs the two characters and exits.  The `b` went straight to the shell (`dash`), as you can see by the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is happening when you execute the posted program:

- `b = getchar();` requests input from standard input.
- no input is pending in the input stream buffer so input is requested from the terminal.
- you type `a` and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
- the terminal is line buffered so the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key produces a newline character in the input stream and control is returned to the program after echoing the `a` and the newline to the terminal (first `a` in the posted execution trace).
- `getchar()` returns the first byte available from the input stream buffer, namely the `a` character.
- `putchar(b);` outputs the `a` to standard output. Standard output is line buffered to the terminal so the character is just stored in the output buffer until a newline is output.
- `y = getchar();` reads the next byte from standard input, which is the newline produced by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key typed for the previous input.
- `putchar(y);` outputs the newline to standard output. The output line is flushed, producing the `a` and a newline (second `a` in the posted execution trace).
- if you then type `b` and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the shell will read this line as a command and try and execute the `b` program, which cannot be found, producing the error message `dash: 2: b: not found`

You might be using some sort of IDE terminal window, if you were testing your program in a shell window, you would see the shell prompt after the second `a` output line.